# Creating an SQL Trigger (using SQLyog)

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I'm having a hard time trying to make a trigger. 
i can find a lot of examples that show how to make triggers, but nothing that helps with my specific issue. 
I need to make a trigger in my exam project and I want it to take the entered email and make it lowercase. Should be quite simple - but i'm not able to do it. 
So now i'm asking for help.

This is what i got from the sql program, and it should be easy to just insert the right values.

```
    DELIMITER $$
 CREATE
/*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
TRIGGER `awesomegame`.`lowercase` AFTER INSERT
ON `awesomegame`.`users`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE LOWER(sEmail);
END$$ DELIMITER ;
```

What do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BEFORE INSERT`  instead of `AFTER INSERT`, and use the new keyword to access and modify the `sEmail` field.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `awesomegame`.`lowercase` BEFORE INSERT ON `awesomegame`.`users` FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.sEmail = LOWER(NEW.sEmail);
```

You can (should ?) do the same thing for `BEFORE UPDATE`.